# why absolute dom remove will cause scroll event even father's height not change

Tags: javascript, html, css

As title say

1. there is a parent dom which is relative and it's height is 5000px.
2. children is absolute and is shorter than parent dom
3. remove item1 will cause scroll

As bellow show, item1 will remove after five seconds. And terminal will console "scroll" after item1 remove. Why this happened? How to prevent scroll in this case?

```js
const removeDom = () => {
  document.getElementById("remove").remove();
}

const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  console.log("scroll")
})

container.scrollTop = 1000;
setTimeout(() => {
  removeDom();
}, 5000)
```

```css
.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 100vh; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="height: 5000px; position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 700px;">
      <div id="remove" class="item">item1</div>
      <div class="item">item2</div>
      <div class="item">item3</div>
      <div class="item">item4</div>
      <div class="item">item5</div>
      <div class="item">item6</div>
      <div class="item">item7</div>
      <div class="item">item8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't explain, but just to note that if instead of removing item1 you set its height to 0px then there is no scroll event fired.

Comment: @AHaworth  Thanks, but I need to remove children in my usecase. Set its height to 0px may cause style effect.

Comment: Yes, I wasn’t suggesting that setting height would be the answer, it was just a comment. I had hoped it would help if we set height 0 and then did the remove but it doesn’t seem to.